# Paypal only able to charge CC - Not send payments

Tags: paypal

My developer is working on integrating Paypal checkout into my website. If I give my developer API credentials, will this allow them to withdraw funds from my account and leave me high and dry?

What I need: Integrate Paypal into my website. Only allow my website to charge and store CC from my clients. NEVER take out funds from my Paypal account.

New to this and need to make sure I wont get burned in this process.

Comment: this is not a programming related question. please refer to paypal's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to Paypal's, you can send payouts with Payouts API and you have to enable it through your account, [see here](https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/article/what-is-the-payouts-api-and-how-do-i-enable-it-on-my-account-ts2075).

> To use the Payouts API, request access through My Account. Alternatively, contact your PayPal Account Manager or PayPal Customer Support. You must have a PayPal business account.